# TSQL: Anyway to determine the error record in a two table update query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to update one table from another using TSQL's UPDATE FROM clause.  In doing so I receive a constraint error.  Is there anyway to trap that error to determine which row is causing the problem?  A TRY/CATCH just outputs the error type/message.

The table I am updating from has 400K records in it.  Is there a better way to deal with this?  A bulk update?  TSQL to loop over the second table? (Though I'm told there are serious performance hits for the latter.)

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

----Update the table and insert values in temp table using Output clause

> UPDATE TestTable  SET TEXTVal = 'NewValue' 
>   OUTPUT Inserted.ID,
>   Inserted.TEXTVal, Deleted.ID, 
>   Deleted.TEXTVal INTO @TmpTable  WHERE ID
>   IN (1,2)

then take a look in the @TmpTable,